# Lockscreen rolling notifications like iPhone

Tags: notifications, lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-note, ios

I like everything about my new Samsung Note 3. It is a superior device in almost every respect to my previous phone the iPhone 5.

But, I have one issue that I have not yet resolved. I cannot get the level of detail notifications that are automatically shown in a rolling notification queue like the iPhone (see images below, iPhone on left, Android on right).

[image] 
[image]

The notifications are shown in the queue in the order they are received regardless of source (sms, email, calendar notification, etc).  They are scrollable vertically, and a swipe takes you to that specific message, event, email, etc.

This is one area the iPhone did very well, and I relied on the timeliness and dependability of that feature.

I have downloaded several lockscreen and notifications apps, but none are close to what I described.

Any suggestion?

I really appreciate any insight. 
Thanks

Comment: What details are you missing from notifications? From what I've seen Android 4's rich notifications show far more detail than iOS ones. What sort of rolling notification queue are you after, something different than the notification shade's rolling notification queue?

Comment: Welcome to the site! It may be a good idea to [edit] your question to be a *lot* more specific than "like iPhone". As Android Enthusiasts, many of us don't have enough experience with iOS to know what this means. Rather than trying to compare apples to oranges (or Apples to Androids), could you please describe specifically what data/functionality you want?

Comment: Thanks for the comment GATrawn.  Are you referring to the built in notification that are displayed for phone, email, sms, calendar?  The trouble is that if you more than one it just groups them and displays a count.  I just glance at the iPhone screen and see if the message content is relevent.  On the Android, I have to open it to see.  That is the key difference for me.

Comment: So does anyone have any input or is something like this just not possible on the Android platform?  Given all of the superior Android features, I think it is minor shortcoming...but it would be nice if there were a workaround someone has found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Slide Lock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.slidelock). It is awesome. Just like iOS version.

[image: screen shot]

<sup>(click image for a larger version)</sup>

Comment: This is just what I was looking for! I searched and searched under "lockscreen" and "notifications", etc and this never came up.  I already bought the Metro Notifications app from this developer, but I never saw this in Google Play.  It's a shame because it is excellent.

Answer (score 1):

Ok.  I didn't get any specific responses/solutions (thanks for the comments I did get thought), but it did prompt me to dig deeper since no one had an answer.

I looked in the Google Play store and found several apps under "Lockscreen", "Notificaitons", or a combination of the two words.  I found several apps that had some good features, but none really came close to providing rich/detailed notifications.  Some apps that I installed and tested.

-[NiLS Notificaitons](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.roymam.android.notificationswidget)

-[WidgetLocker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.widgetlocker)

-[Lock Screen Notifications](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samr.notificationWallpaper)

-[Espier Notifications-  this one was promising, but never worked quite right](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.espier.launcher.plugin.notifications7)

In the end, I found one APP that doesnt show up with the keywords "Lockscreen" or "Notificaitons".
This APP required a lot of configuration, and you have to install some helper email apps.  But the final result is acceptable(image below).  It also has some nice features, like the ability to add widgets (in this case I added a weather widget).  I could never do that on iPhone, so it may be a good trade off.

[Executive Assistant Paid Version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appventive.ExecAssist&hl=en) 
AND 
[Executive Assistant Free Version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appventive.ExecAssist.ad&hl=en)

I hope this helps anyone looking for rich "iPhone" like notifications.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can try [Echo Lockscreen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.doublelabs.androscreen.echo&hl=en) which does this.